# Deploy Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my ruby on rails application on a DigitalOcean server. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 x64, Passenger 5.0.10 and Apache 2 to deploy. I followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial. When I try to run my application on production environment I get this error "We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly." I can run on development environment.

This are the Apache 2 access.log:

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 495 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 494 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 505 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "http://kproxy.com/doproxy.jsp" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.8$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 3339 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 64889 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.$
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 66303 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"
"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 295 "http://45.55.92.193/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.
```

This are the Apache 2 error.log:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.5.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:14:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:55:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/rails/App/newdvp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:3:in `require'
config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:107:in `preload_app'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.10/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'

[ 2015-06-16 02:34:33.2422 9276/7f74f0b2e700 
age/Hel/Req/CheckoutSession.cpp:252 ]: [Client 1-5] 
Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. 
The identifier of the error is 74aaa4d4. Please see ear$
```

My database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dvp_development
  pool: 5
  username: rails
  password:
  host: localhost 

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dvp_development
  pool: 5
  username: 
  password: 

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: dvp_development
  pool: 5
  username: rails
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Comment: I believe you should check the database.yml which is in .... /config/database.yml... and look for the production place ... that tutorial works fine for me .

Comment: I edited with my database.yml. Do yours look like this?

Comment: No sir .... mine was not like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following option to your apache virtual host :

`PassengerFriendlyErrorPages on`

It permits apache/passenger to display a friendly error page. Hope it will help.